# How do I calculate the difference between two timestamps?

Tags: sql, sqlite, date-arithmetic, strftime

How to calculate the difference in minutes between timestamps `TIMEIN` and `TIMEOUT`? My table (only 3 rows):

| DATE | TIMEIN | TIMEOUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-05-06 | 14:00 | 15:00 |
| 2020-05-06 | 14:45 | 15:55 |
| 2020-05-07 | 09:00 | 10:45 |

My SQL doesn't output what I want:

```
SELECT (T.DATE + T.TIMEIN - T.DATE + T.TIMEOUT) AS `Duration`

FROM Transport T;
```

Output:

| Duration |
| --- |
| 29 |
| 29 |
| 19 |

It should be :

| Duration |
| --- |
| 60 |
| 70 |
| 105 |

I tried this without using the date, however that lead to an output of -1 for all rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `TIMEOUT` is always greater than `TIMEIN` you can subtract the unix epochs of the 2 values and divide by 60 to get the number of minutes:

```
SELECT (strftime('%s', TIMEOUT) - strftime('%s', TIMEIN)) / 60 AS Duration
FROM Transport;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/LegKVy3S).

Answer (score -1):

date/time is not like integers so they didn't add/subtract like integers. So convert them in a timestamp before subtraction.